# deploy war file on jboss in eclipse ide

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, jboss7.x

I am using jboss 7.1 and have integrated it in my eclipse kepler.
I need to deploy my .war created by maven on this server and run it.

I don't want to deploy it externally by pasting the war in jboss directory. I want to do it internally in eclipse.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse-jboss integration (Eclipse integrates with all popular applications servers out of the box) or you can use maven-deploy-plugin/maven-war-plugin or something like this.